# Console on windows-subsystem-for-linux slow when entering text

Tags: tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, byobu

I'm using the [windows-subsystem-for-linux](/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux) console.  Recently it sometimes pauses when typing text, the typed text appears after a few seconds.  In the past it worked fine.

I'm searching for what causes this and how I can fix it.

- I thought it might be caused by the command completion in bash together with the environment from the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt (see this question's history)
  This seems not to be the case:

  - The delays happen without the environment from the Visual Studio Developer command prompt.
  - The delays also happen when I type an answer to a prompt from `git add --patch`.

Perhaps it is [tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux) (I'm using version 1.8) or [byobu](/questions/tagged/byobu) (version 5.74) in combination with the windows conconsole?

What causes this problem?
How can I make bash responsive again?

Comment: Also experiencing this :( Not fun after getting very comfortable with byobu. As a note, it only seems to happen locally. It doesn't seem to occur if I ssh into my server from WSL, then use byobu on the server side (ubuntu).

Comment: Also, do you have additional spinning HDDs in your computer? The lag time seems comparable to the time it takes for windows to spin up one of my HDDs in general. Might have something to do with mounted drives being checked.